# problem inserting record in Sqlite table using QSQLTable model and QDataWidget mapper

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm struggling with the code shown below that loads data from a SQLite table which has 3 columns ("codice" (primary key, autoincrement), "descrizione", "peso") using QSQLTable model with QDataWidget mapper.

My problem is I defined a QPushButton to insert new record in such table but I'm not able to get it work. I tried different ways using self.model.insertRows or self.model.insertRecord but I was not successfully. I'm not getting any error but the record is not inserted.

For sure there are conceptual errors I can't catch.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QComboBox,
    QDataWidgetMapper,
    QDoubleSpinBox,
    QFormLayout,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QLabel,
    QLineEdit,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QSpinBox,
    QTableView,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)
from connect_SQLITE import Database

db=Database.con
db.open()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        form = QFormLayout()

        self.codice = QSpinBox()
        self.codice.setRange(0, 2147483647)
        self.codice.setDisabled(True)
        
        self.descrizione = QLineEdit()
        
        self.peso = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.peso.setDecimals(5)
        self.peso.setRange(0, 9999.99999)
        self.peso.setSingleStep(0.01)

        form.addRow(QLabel("Codice Materiale"), self.codice)
        form.addRow(QLabel("Nome Materiale"), self.descrizione)
        form.addRow(QLabel("Peso specifico Materiale (Kg/dm3)"), self.peso)

        self.model = QSqlTableModel(db=db)
        self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper()
        self.mapper.setModel(self.model)

        self.mapper.addMapping(self.codice, 0)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.descrizione, 1)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.peso, 2)

        self.model.setTable("Prova")
        self.model.select()

        self.mapper.toFirst()

        # tag::controls[]
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(400, 400))

        controls = QHBoxLayout()

        prev_rec = QPushButton("Precedente")
        prev_rec.clicked.connect(self.mapper.toPrevious)

        next_rec = QPushButton("Successivo")
        next_rec.clicked.connect(self.mapper.toNext)

        ins_rec = QPushButton("Inserimento")
        ins_rec.clicked.connect(self.inserimento_materiale)
        
        save_rec = QPushButton("Salvataggio modifiche")
        save_rec.clicked.connect(self.mapper.submit)

        controls.addWidget(prev_rec)
        controls.addWidget(next_rec)
        controls.addWidget(ins_rec)
        controls.addWidget(save_rec)

        layout.addLayout(form)
        layout.addLayout(controls)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        # end::controls[]

    def inserimento_materiale(self):
        self.model.insertRows(self.model.rowCount(), 1)
        self.model.setData(self.model.index(0,1), self.descrizione.text())
        self.model.setData(self.model.index(0,2), self.peso)
        self.model.submit()
     

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: I changed as per your suggetion and it works perfectly. Thanks for the explanation and the hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by default the mapper uses the `AutoSubmit` [`submitPolicy()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatawidgetmapper.html#submitPolicy-prop):

> Whenever a widget loses focus, the widget's current value is set to the item model.

And QSqlTableModel uses the `OnRowChange` [`editStrategy()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#editStrategy):

> Changes to a row will be applied when the user selects a different row.

Also, you're calling `setData()` on the first row, instead of the *new* one.

The result is that when `inserimento_materiale` is called and a new row is inserted, the current index of the mapper is still the previous one (the first on startup, due to `toFirst()` or any other set after `toPrevious()` or `toNext()`), `setData()` will not work in any case:

- in your example, the mapper has already set the cached data due to its `AutoSubmit` policy, but it has not been actually submitted in the database, and [`setData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setData) returns `False` because "For OnRowChange, an index may receive a change only if no other row has a cached change";
- even setting the proper row for `setData()` will not work, as inserting a new row causes the mapper to submit the previous data of the current widgets in the previous row, and will not properly update the new mapper index;

<sup>Be aware that your code also has a typo: you're trying to call `setData()` with `self.peso` which is a widget.</sup>

A possible solution is to read the current widget values *before doing anything*, [`revert()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#revert) the model data (to avoid saving the new data on the previous index), submit the new data to the model and set the new index in the mapper:

```
    def inserimento_materiale(self):
        descrizione = self.descrizione.text()
        peso = self.peso.value()
        self.model.revert()
        row = self.model.rowCount()
        self.model.insertRow(row)
        self.model.setData(self.model.index(row, 1), descrizione)
        self.model.setData(self.model.index(row, 2), peso)
        self.model.submitAll()
        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(row)
```

Note that since you have a dedicated submit button, you should change the mapper's submit policy to `ManualSubmit`, which makes things easier:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.mapper.setSubmitPolicy(self.mapper.ManualSubmit)

    def inserimento_materiale(self):
        row = self.model.rowCount()
        self.model.insertRow(row)
        self.model.setData(self.model.index(row, 1), self.descrizione.text())
        self.model.setData(self.model.index(row, 2), self.peso.value())
        self.model.submitAll()
        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(row)
```